# I get a CORS-Error while doing a request for a API using XHR

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest, cors

We’re making a request for an API from one of our online-distributors.
However, we get a CORS-Error.

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.cloud.im/marketplace/eu/products' from origin 'http://www.im-cmp.ch' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

We did the request in Postman and it worked. I tried to set the requestHeaders the exact same way they are set in Postman (including the hidden headers), however, there is an Error since the hidden headers can’t be set.

*Refused to set unsafe header "Host"*

Is this a client or a server problem? Am I maybe missing a requestHeader?

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.withCredentials = true;

  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if(this.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
   }
  });

  xhr.open("GET", "https://api.cloud.im/marketplace/eu/products");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Subscription-Key", "OUR PERSONAL SUBSCRIPTION KEY"); 
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OUR BEARER TOKEN");
  //      xhr.setRequestHeader("Host", "http://www.im-cmp.ch/");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "*/*");
  //      xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
  //      xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
  xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a server problem.

The server has to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`-header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS.

Also, the error states that this happened during a `preflight`-request, meaning there was a `OPTIONS` request made beforehand, which would also need the response-header(s) needed for CORS.

The request works in Postman, since CORS is a feature only really relevant in browsers, to protect users.

**Edit:**

Also it is important that the server allows the request-headers you are sending using the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`-header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers